# Taking table name as input in sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to take a table name as input from user to my PL / SQL script and then update that table. I am not sure if this is possible because ORACLE might have problem parsing the script.

Please guild me as to how to solve this problem.

Thnx.

Answer (score 4):

Use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.  It allows you to build a SQL statement as a VARCHAR2 string and then execute that statement.

eg.

```
lStr := 'UPDATE '||table-name||' SET COLUMN-NAME = VALUE';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lStr;
```

COLUMN-NAME and VALUE can also be changed dynamically of course.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm

Comment: Look at DBMS_ASSERT to validate the table name being passed in.